# Docker-compose volumes not being mounted

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I have a simple ASP.net Core project that I run in a docker container using docker-compose. I am trying to mount a host directory in order to save some files, for example log files.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 55498
EXPOSE 44396

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY calibration-upload-server/calibration-upload-server.csproj calibration-upload-server/
RUN dotnet restore calibration-upload-server/calibration-upload-server.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/calibration-upload-server
RUN dotnet build calibration-upload-server.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish calibration-upload-server.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "calibration-upload-server.dll"]
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  calibration-upload-server:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}calibration-upload-server
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: calibration-upload-server/Dockerfile
volumes:
- C:/Uploads/logs:/logs
```

When building the solution in Visual studio, docker compose seems able to parse file, and the volumes group looks like this:

```
volumes:
- C:\Uploads\logs:/logs:rw
- C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
- C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

So it seems the file got parsed correctly (the other two volumes are from the override file). But when I run the solution, `docker run` is run without this volume:

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\UserName\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Repos\calibration-upload-server\calibration-upload-server:/app" -v "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44396" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -p 55498:80 -p 44396:443 --entrypoint tail calibrationuploadserver:dev -f /dev/null
```

The most frustrating part is that this *worked just fine*, until I renamed the solution and project. I have no idea if this is what broke it or not, but still.

One more thing that might be relevant, when building I get warned that `The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Is there anyway to figure out where the error is?